# Unable to Install Jmeter plugin manager in docker image

Tags: docker, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am working on creating a docker image for running jmeter tests with plugins, but I am stuck at point where the jmeter plugin manager wont install. I tried most of things on the internet but with no luck.

I tried using existing docker images on the hub but everything fails on finding the class for pluginmanager.

Below is the error I get:

> Step 16/23 : RUN cd $JMETER_HOME && java -cp /lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.4.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
> ---> Running in d2d5579a4832

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
> The command '/bin/sh -c cd $JMETER_HOME && java -cp /lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.4.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller' returned a non-zero code: 1

Answer (score 2):

> Could not find or load main class org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller

it means that your [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) doesn't contain  `PluginManagerCMDInstaller` class.

My expectation is that you need to remove the slash before `/lib` as in Linux paths which start from slash are considered [absolute and most probably you need to use the relative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) one:

```
 RUN cd $JMETER_HOME && java -cp lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.4.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
```

More information:

- [How to Install the JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
- [Plugins Manager from Command-Line](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/)